# Add an ID to a canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to add an ID to a canvas using JavaScript however I'm trying to modify the following specific code. Please note, I am only assuming that this is where I would set the attribute. Cheers for any help.

```
THREE.CanvasRenderer = function ( parameters ) {

console.log( 'THREE.CanvasRenderer', THREE.REVISION );

parameters = parameters || {};

var _this = this,
    _renderData, _elements, _lights,
    _projector = new THREE.Projector(),

    _canvas = parameters.canvas !== undefined
             ? parameters.canvas
             : document.createElement( 'canvas' ),

    _canvasWidth = _canvas.width,
    _canvasHeight = _canvas.height,
    _canvasWidthHalf = Math.floor( _canvasWidth / 2 ),
    _canvasHeightHalf = Math.floor( _canvasHeight / 2 ),

    _viewportX = 0,
    _viewportY = 0,
    _viewportWidth = _canvasWidth,
    _viewportHeight = _canvasHeight,

    _pixelRatio = 1,

    _context = _canvas.getContext( '2d', {
        alpha: parameters.alpha === true
    } ),
```

Comment: You're assuming.... does this mean you don't really understand the source code you're using? Also where are your trying to add the `ID` as I see no attempt.....

Comment: just add `_canvas.id="desired-id";` before the `_canvasWidth` line

Comment: Yeah that didn't work, thanks anyway Tudor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set the `id` property directly:

```
_canvas.id = 'whatever';
```

**Edit**

The above code should work, but it will need to be after the large variable initialization block you have:

```
// start var initialization
var _this = this,
    _renderData, _elements, _lights,
    _projector = new THREE.Projector(),

    _canvas = parameters.canvas !== undefined
             ? parameters.canvas
             : document.createElement( 'canvas' ),

    _canvasWidth = _canvas.width,
    _canvasHeight = _canvas.height,
    _canvasWidthHalf = Math.floor( _canvasWidth / 2 ),
    _canvasHeightHalf = Math.floor( _canvasHeight / 2 ),

    _viewportX = 0,
    _viewportY = 0,
    _viewportWidth = _canvasWidth,
    _viewportHeight = _canvasHeight,

    _pixelRatio = 1,

    _context = _canvas.getContext( '2d', {
        alpha: parameters.alpha === true
    } ),

    ... more code,

    theEnd = true;
// end var initialization

_canvas.id = 'whatever';
```

^ this whole thing is one big var initialization. At some point there it will end and there will probably be a semicolon. That's where you will add the id code.

I think you were getting an unexpected token error because you were trying to add some code between the commas in the var initialization.

Comment: Thanks Austin, I already tried that but it just breaks the code :(

Comment: This should work as long as `_canvas` is a dom node -- so the `document.createElement( 'canvas' )` should be fine, but maybe you are passing in something other than a dom node as a parameter? What's the error you get? does `_canvas.width`, etc work correctly?

Comment: @Mitzi When you say it breaks the code, the would normally end up with some error, please check your browser console for errors, if you see one please post it in your next comment as this can help and possibly lead to a solid solution. Thank you.

Comment: The error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

It doesn't break if I try  _canvasId = 'whatever',

However, the id isn't added

Comment: I see, you have a really big var block with commas, I think that's the problem. I'll update my answer above.

Comment: @AustinGreco that worked, you're a legend! Thanks heaps :)